# async causes debugger jump

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
private async Task<DataSharedTheatres.TheatresPayload> GetTheatres()
{
    var callMgr = new ApiCallsManager();
    var fileMgr = new FileSystemManager();

    string cachedTheatres = fileMgr.ReadFile(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TheatreTemp.txt"));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cachedTheatres))
    {
        **string generalModelPull = await callMgr.GetData(new Uri("somecrazyapi.com/api" + apiAccessKey));**
        bool saveResult = fileMgr.WriteToFile(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TheatreTemp.txt"), generalModelPull);
        if (!saveResult)
        {
            testText.Text = "Failed to load Theatre Data";
            return null;
        }
        cachedTheatres = fileMgr.ReadFile(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TheatreTemp.txt"));
    }
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSharedTheatres.TheatresPayload>(cachedTheatres);
**}**
```

I set the breakpoint on the first highlighted line (which it hits), then I press F10, and debugger jumps to the last bracket! I am not understanding why.

GetData method:

```
public async Task<string> GetData(Uri source)
{
    if (client.IsBusy) 
        client.CancelAsync ();
    string result = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync (source);
    return result;


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's what "await" does. When you use "await" in an async method, it tells the compiler that you want the method to return at that point, and then to re-enter the method later only when the "awaited" task has completed.

Comment: That sounds fair, but pressing F10 again and again does not push the debugger any further, at least in my case. In fact it appears stuck. Can this happen if the awaited task is failing?

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio are you using? If something other than Express, then open the Threads window (Ctrl-D, T). If Express, then you'll have to make do with the Call Stack window (unless the newest Express edition now supports the Threads window...it didn't used to). While you are stepping through, pay close attention to the Threads and/or Call Stack window, and notice how your context switches between threads. This is Visual Studio trying to be helpful. Sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not so much. :)