# ASP.NET MVC Controller actions -code runs chaotically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have really no ideea how to ask this. I have a set of async actions in my controller, one of which should populate a list through a foreach statement. The strange thing is, imagine I have 10 lines of code, it runs line 1 then jumps to line 4 then line 10 then line 1 again, at one point, the list has all the items it should but then it jumps again to the first line where I declared that list and then it exists with the empty list. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Here is the action in question

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetBuyingListItems(string buyingListId, string vendorId, string orderId)
{
    var buyingListService = new BuyingListService(_buyingListRepository);
    ItemService itemService = new ItemService(_itemRepository);
    var vendorService = new VendorService(_vendorRepository);
    om.BuyingList = await buyingListService.GetOne(buyingListId);
    om.BuyingListItems = await buyingListService.GetBuyingListItems(buyingListId);
    om.Vendor = await vendorService.GetOne(vendorId);
    om.ItemsList = new List<OrderItemsDTO>();
    foreach (var buyingListItem in om.BuyingListItems)
    {
        var item = await itemService.GetOne(buyingListItem.ItemId);
        var orderItem = new OrderItemsDTO();
        orderItem.OrderId = orderId;
        orderItem.ItemID = item.Id;
        orderItem.Qty = buyingListItem.Qty;
        orderItem.TotalPrice = item.UnitPrice * buyingListItem.Qty;
        orderItem.Currency = om.Vendor.Currency;
        orderItem.VendorId = om.Vendor.Id;
        om.ItemsList.Add(orderItem);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ItemListWithBuyingList", new { vendorId = vendorId, orderId = orderId, ItemsList = om.ItemsList });
}
```

om -> this is the model, i declered it  for the entire controller.

P.s. I have no ideea how to formulate this question in order to search for the answer so sorry if it's already been answered.

p.p.s. this isn't the only method that runs like this but i never had this problem until now. I always assumed it's because it runs asynchroniously.

p.p.p.s this might help, if i'm debuging from the browser, on the network part, my ajax calls are being made multiple times (for instance: first time - 3 times, then 6, then 12, etc... ). I am returning false on my ajax calls and there's no href="#" in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer unless you include some code in the question

Comment: just added the code, thank you

Comment: [Debugging Asynchronous Code in Visual Studio 2013 - Tasks Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/02/debugging-asynchronous-code-in-visual-studio-2013-tasks-window.aspx)

Comment: [Walkthrough: Using the Debugger with Async Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155813.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async causes debugger jump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479056/async-causes-debugger-jump)

Comment: Liam, i know this is how async works, but considering i have 4 items in om.BuyingListItems, it should re-enter that block when it hase those items and insert them into my list, at the end, it should get my list with those 4 items, but for some reason it gets the items into the list, then deletes them and returns an emtpy list.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is quite common when deubgging code that is being accessed by multiple threads. It looks chaotic but it's simply down to debugging jumping across different threads.

As a start you can use "lock" to avoid this during debugging so you can concentrate on the business logic not the threading issue.

Comment: Adding a lock into a thread will be a very bad idea essentially turning your async code into synchronous code

Comment: I just tried it but it still jumps all over the place and the list is returned empty (i have 4 items in om.BuyingListItems)

Comment: Thanks Liam. To make it clear I'm suggesting to use lock just for debugging business logic. I am not suggesting this is a permanent solution.

Comment: what's your lock code like? you probably need to lock on a static object in order to debug the logic

Comment: Thanx all for your help, the reason for my calls jumping all over was a function on $(document).ajaxComplete(.....), it was calling that action all over again, I still have to figure out why my list is empty but at least now when it's passed from this method it has all the items in it. Thank you all again :)